# Using Massive; in a WPF Application with EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, massive

I want to use Massive ORM(by Rob Conerys) in a WPF Application using Entity Framework.

It sais to add in app.config the providerName = 'System.Data.SqlClient'
but using EF I have System.Data.EntityClient and I get this error : "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Massive and EF are alternatives; you don't generally use both. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the application's debug mode to x86 as oppose to 'any computer' ? i had that error for the longest time and that's how i solved it , you can set it in the white drop down box at the top that usually has 'debug' in it, u drop down and click configuration manager, and then change the top right option.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating a second connection string specifically for Massive.